# what is the recursive way to print this if I dont know the depth of category array

Tags: javascript, recursion

what is the ways to print this code if I don't know the category object depth?
How to map this to get as recursive category under category with different circumstances?

```
const category =  [{"id":8,"name":"Genere","parent":null,"category":[]},
{"id":1,"name":"Movies","parent":null,"category":[{
"id":2,"name":"Bollywood","parent":1,"category":[]
},
{"id":3,"name":"Hollywood","parent":1,"category":[]}
]},
{"id":9,"name":"Region","parent":null,"category":[]},
{"id":4,"name":"Songs","parent":null,"category":[{"id":7,"name":"Bollywood","parent":4,"category":[{"id":10,"name":"Arijit singh","parent":7,"category":[]},
{"id":11,"name":"Sonu Nigam","parent":7,"category":[]}]},
{"id":6,"name":"English","parent":4,"category":[]},
{"id":5,"name":"Hindi","parent":4,"category":[]}]
}]
const printCategory = category.map((cat, i) => {
    return (
        console.log(cat.name + " ------> "  + i),
        cat.category.map((c, i) => {
            console.log(c.name + " ------> " + i),
            c.category.map((ca, i) => {
                console.log(ca.name + " ------> " + i)
            })
        })
        )
})
```

Comment: actually, you do not return something meaning full with mapping ...?

Answer (score 2):

```
const printCategory = (c, i) => {
   console.log(c.name + " ------> "  + i)
   c.category.map(printCategory);
}
category.map(printCategory);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same callback for each nested category.

```js
const
    x = ({ name, category }, i) => {
        console.log(name, i);
        category.forEach(x);
    },
    category = [{ id: 8, name: "Genere", parent: null, category: [] }, { id: 1, name: "Movies", parent: null, category: [{ id: 2, name: "Bollywood", parent: 1, category: [] }, { id: 3, name: "Hollywood", parent: 1, category: [] }] }, { id: 9, name: "Region", parent: null, category: [] }, { id: 4, name: "Songs", parent: null, category: [{ id: 7, name: "Bollywood", parent: 4, category: [{ id: 10, name: "Arijit singh", parent: 7, category: [] }, { id: 11, name: "Sonu Nigam", parent: 7, category: [] }] }, { id: 6, name: "English", parent: 4, category: [] }, { id: 5, name: "Hindi", parent: 4, category: [] }] }];

category.forEach(x);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

just use a regular recursive function, if category doesn't exist or it is empty, just return.

```js
const category = [{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Genere",
    "parent": null,
    "category": []
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Movies",
    "parent": null,
    "category": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bollywood",
        "parent": 1,
        "category": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Hollywood",
        "parent": 1,
        "category": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Region",
    "parent": null,
    "category": []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Songs",
    "parent": null,
    "category": [{
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Bollywood",
        "parent": 4,
        "category": [{
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Arijit singh",
            "parent": 7,
            "category": []
          },
          {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Sonu Nigam",
            "parent": 7,
            "category": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "English",
        "parent": 4,
        "category": []
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Hindi",
        "parent": 4,
        "category": []
      }
    ]
  }
]

function recursiveLoop(array) {
  if (!array) return;
  array.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.name);
    recursiveLoop(item.category)
  })
}

recursiveLoop(category);
```